# How to read xml file from file system into InputStream without using the assets folder in Android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, inputstream

I need to parse an xml file from my phone sdcard. I was able to do the same by putting the file inside the assets folder
by using the code

```
 ` InputStream in_s = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("Credentials.xml");`
```

But i need to get it from the sdcard maybe by providing

```
`new  File("/sdcard/TestProj/Credentials.xml") `
```

as a parameter.
I know

`StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/sdcard/TestProj/Credentials.xml"));`

is a way to obtain the file in a StreamResult. But i am not able to find a way to convert that to InputStream.

I just tried 
`StreamSource result = new StreamSource(new File("/sdcard/TestProj/Credentials.xml"));`

but result.getInputStream() gave null pointer

Comment: The file.canRead() does retun true which means the file is readable but once i pass it to "StreamSource result" . the result.getInputStream() gives null. Is the StreamSource not meant to be used with XML's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used FileInputstream instead for SourceStream and it worked!